# My jupyter notebook is not launching, when l try to run it it glitches and exits in less than 2 seconds, when l try is in anaconda l get a long error

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2025, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 280, in launch_instance
super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1051, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 575, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1311, in __new__
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1354, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1330, in setup_instance
init(self)
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

I tried reinstalling the application but didn't work

Comment: In general, it's a smell for _some_ libraries to be coming from conda and some to be coming from a different non-conda-managed interpreter. Don't mix your PYTHONPATHs -- make sure you're only using libraries installed for the specific interpreter you're using.

Comment: Also, however you copied-and-pasted the stack trace into the post lost the indentation; if you can, please try to fix that.

Comment: This is related to a breaking change in `traitlets`. Downgrade to 5.9.0 or below.